# How to Search for % using SQL and Wildcards?

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, wildcard

I have to replace % in a number of fields.  I need to get a list of the records to be changed first.  I know how to do the actual REPLACE easily enough, but my query to find the records isn't working correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE desc LIKE '%%%'
```

I also tried the following the the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE desc LIKE '%'+CHAR(37)+'%'
```

What's the best way to search for %?

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: One way: LIKE '%[%]%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the wildcard:

```
where [desc] like '%$%%' escape '$'
```

or, use a character class:

```
where [desc] like '%[%]%'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, it is exactly what I needed.